# Why is the styling for the span class in the css styling sheet not working?

Tags: css

I'm trying to style the span class and it does not change anything. I can't figure out why everything else is working and not this. This is my HTML code:

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="firstDiv">
      <img src="Images\parisImage.jpg" alt="Paris" id="parisImage">
      <p id="title">Terps Calculators Inc.</p>
      <img src="Images/pineapple.jpg" alt="pineapple" id="pineappleImage" />
    </div>
    <div class="secondDiv">
      <ul id="linkList">
        <li><a class="link" href="Http://www.google.com">www.google.com ,</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="link" href="Http://www.hamodia.com">www.hamodia.com ,</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="link " href="Http://www.gmail.com">www.gmail.com</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="thirdDiv">
      <h1 class="heading">Intoduction</h1>
      <p><span class="bold">Terps Calculators Inc.</span><span class="italic">implements and provides these<br/> calculators for     your use. We keep expanding our collection<br/> every day so make sure you stop by often.</span>
      </p>
      <h1 class="heading">Calculators</h1>
      <ul class="calculators">
        <li><a class="link2" href="GradesCalculator.html">Grades Calculator</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="link2" href="InterestCalculator.html">Interest Calculator</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fourthDiv">
      <p id="title2">Terps Calculators inc. &reg</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is working. Whatever the problem is, you didn't include it in your question. You need to create a [MCVE] (with special attention to the **Verifiable** part).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. The code you posted seems to [work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tbpLn4L1/).

Comment: when i comment out all the other code in the style sheet, it works so i guess that something is overriding it and i can't figure out what.

Comment: If you can't find what's overriding it, you can always use .bold {font-weight: bold !important;} .italic {font-style: italic !important;}

Answer (score -1):

Based on a comment you provided, this appears to be a case of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Here, your `.bold` and `.italic` selectors aren't specific enough to override your other rules. As MDN notes:

> The following list of selector types is by increasing specificity:
>
> 1. Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., :before).
> 2. Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
> 3. ID selectors (e.g., #example).

There are many [CSS specificity calculators](https://www.google.com?q=css%20specificity%20calculator) available online and you can use them to easily calculate what rules will be applied.